# Ambiguous error in Lookup Override for teradata query

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica-powercenter

I am using below self join query as Lookup override in informatica. This is running        fine in teradata.

```
SELECT A.region_cd AS REGION_CODE, 
       A.enp_no    AS ENP_NBR, 
       B.sla_cd    AS SLA_CODE 
FROM   edb_man_work.emp A, 
       edb_man_work.emp B 
WHERE  A.company_no = Trim(Cast(B.enp_no AS INTEGER)) 
       AND A.region_cd = B.region_cd
```

This is running fine in teradata but while running in mapping it is giving error

as Column SLA_CD is ambiguous.

I am not sure why this is giving this type of error.

Comment: Can you please share the query Informatica is generating from the session log. Might be the issue is in the ORDER BY clause that Informatica appends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using multiple source tables, make sure you end the Lookup SQL override with --.

If you look at the session log, you'll see that Informatica automatically appends Lookup SQL overrides with an ORDER BY statement. Adding the -- will comment out this addition.

```
SELECT A.region_cd AS REGION_CODE, 
       A.enp_no    AS ENP_NBR, 
       B.sla_cd    AS SLA_CODE 
FROM   edb_man_work.emp A, 
       edb_man_work.emp B 
WHERE  A.company_no = Trim(Cast(B.enp_no AS INTEGER)) 
       AND A.region_cd = B.region_cd 
--
```